# Cyrus' Adventure (Part 8)

Tags: word, wordplay, language

After tapping on the wall, it opened automatically. Inside was another corridor - as damp as the previous one. "Eww!" exclaimed Cyrus.
At the end of the corridor, a huge stone tablet blocked the road. On the tablet were three symbols: a green horse, a blue mouse and a red river. Buttons were installed above the three symbols.

"Hmm... interesting symbols," said Cyrus.

Here comes the question. Which button should Cyrus press?

Hint: (must read)

> 青梅竹鼠 江黃不接

Comment: Sorry for updating late! I will try updating one part per week as I'm running out of ideas ;)

Comment: @Omega Krypton thx for the edit bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He should press the

> green horse

For the colours,

> ignore them

For the patterns,

> mouse 鼠 and river 江 has been covered, **except horse**

Comment: Ahem Ahem you should not ignore the colors

Comment: Omega Krypton XDXD

Comment: You love it so I add it

Comment: Btw 鼠 and 江 were the first things that came to my mind

Comment: 江······ you know why

Answer (score 3):

He should press the

> green horse

But for a different reason than [Omega Krypton](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/83547/30558).

> Given phrases are incorrect. Correct ones are:
> 青梅竹*馬* ('horse' instead of 'rat')
> *青*黃不接 ('green' instead of 'river')
> So the button to be pressed is 青馬 - Green Horse.

Comment: I'm struggling... whose answer should I accept? Both of you are correct

Comment: But my initial thought was same as yours :)

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was not accepted, if this was the intended reasoning. +1 from me, regardless.

Comment: I'm guessing... first come, first served.

Answer (score 1):

When using

> Google Translate, the words translate to “Green Plum Bamboo Mouse”. If I assume that it was mistranslated, I’m going to assume that Green Horse and Blue Mouse are already covered.

Therefore Cyrus should press

> Red River

Comment: I thought it was mistranslated but for a different reason.  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9D%92%E6%A2%85%E7%AB%B9%E9%A6%AC

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Try again!

Answer (score 1):

From the hint I get

> Green Plum Bamboo Rat jiang Huang do not answer, translation courtesy of https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary

Further research came up with this:

> A video explaining the meaning of "Green Plum Bamboo Horse" -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaW5fUiiXgY

More research later...

> Jiang Huang is an herb that helps to activate the blood, and one description I found also stated it helps initiate menstrual flow which could elude to 'red river'.

Thus,

> The combination of "Green Plum Bamboo Horse" as explained in the aforementioned video eludes to a childhood toy horse. Add 'red river' followed by 'do not answer', I concluded both of these were not the answer. Cyrus should choose the blue mouse.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the correct answer. Try again!